# Spline interpolation over 3 variables for scattered data in Python?

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation, n-dimensional

With other words I got a set of data-points (x,y,z) associated to a value b and I would like to interpolate this data as accurate as possible. 
Scipy.interpolate.griddata only can do a linear interpolation, what are the other options?

Answer (score 0):

How about interpolating x, y, z separatly? I modified [this](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_examples/mplot3d/lines3d_demo.py) tutorial example and added interpolation to it:

```python
import matplotlib as mpl
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import InterpolatedUnivariateSpline

mpl.rcParams['legend.fontsize'] = 10

# let's take only 20 points for original data:
n = 20

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
theta = np.linspace(-4 * np.pi, 4 * np.pi, n)
z = np.linspace(-2, 2, n)
r = z**2 + 1
x = r * np.sin(theta)
y = r * np.cos(theta)
ax.plot(x, y, z, label='rough curve')

# this variable represents distance along the curve:
t = np.arange(n)

# now let's refine it to 100 points:
t2 = np.linspace(t.min(), t.max(), 100)

# interpolate vector components separately:
x2 = InterpolatedUnivariateSpline(t, x)(t2)
y2 = InterpolatedUnivariateSpline(t, y)(t2)
z2 = InterpolatedUnivariateSpline(t, z)(t2)

ax.plot(x2, y2, z2, label='interpolated curve')

ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

The result looks like this:
[image: 3d line plot]

**UPDATE**

Didn't understand the question at the first time, sorry.

You are probably looking for tricubic interpolation. Try [this](https://github.com/danielguterding/pytricubic).

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Making use of parametrization isn't an option in my case because I don't know what the parametrization would be...

Comment: Yeah, i thought you need to interpolate a line. See updated answer.

Comment: Tricubic interpolation is for equally spaced coordinates, mine are scattered. Anyway, I went through a lot of different methods, and I think my only option is to do a linear interpolation and hence use scipy.interpolate.griddata().